# Table of Figures and longtable package

Tags: longtable

I'm writing my thesis with my school template, but I have a problem when I'm using the longtable package. In the list of table, I only have the number of the figure (3.1 for example) instead of (Figure 3.1). I don't have this problem with the usual table package. Here is the school code to insert the Figure and Table word in the list of table. Is there a way to modify it to take longtable caption into consideration?

Thanks for your help.

```
    % Définition de \caption pour inclure le mot FIGURE ou TABLEAU.
\def\caption{\refstepcounter\@captype \@dblarg{\@caption\@captype}}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide the code of a *complete* document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Most questions can only be reliably answered when seeing the complete context (like the class or the way how commands are used).